# onReadyStateChange not firing in IE for XHR Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, http, xmlhttprequest

I have this code that I am using and it works fine in chrome, but in IE, it looks like that onreadystatechenge is not firing.

How do I get this to work cross browser. I read that in IE you have to place the onreadystatechange event before the send, But that didn't work.

The alert here is not firing. And yes it is successful.

```
if (xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("DONE!");
    }
```

This is the entire request.

```
function SendFile(evt)
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#FileUpload1").get(0).files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{

    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt)
{
    if (evt.lengthComputable)
    {
        var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", progress);
    }
}, false);
xhr.open("POST", "Handler.ashx");

xhr.onreadystatechange=function ()
{
    if (xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("DONE!");
    }
}
xhr.send(data);


$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    max: 100,
    change: function (evt, ui)
    {
        $("#progresslabel").text($("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
    },
    complete: function (evt, ui)
    {
        $("#progresslabel").text("File upload successful!");
        GetID();
    }
});
```

}

Tried onload with no luck.

```
   xhr.onload = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
            alert("IE DONE!");

        }
    }
```

Comment: That’s weird, because `xhr.readyState` can only go from 0 to 4 but not 200.

Comment: Sorry i wronte that in by hand. It is actually 4.Fixed.

Comment: Would it still not work if you’d remove that `xhr.status==200 &&`?

Comment: Since that you're using jQuery, you may want to try using the `$.ajax()` method instead of a regular Javascript XHR.

Comment: Looks like removing xhr returns readyState in IE but not the status, i dont have the time to find out why right now. That will have to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Your `XMLHttpRequest` object might be caching.

Try:

```
var myNoCachePage = document.location + '?' + new Date().getTime();
xhr.open("GET", myNoCachePage, true);  // Prevent IE11 from caching
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently IE 11 (which I assume is what you are testing is broken) removed `script.onreadystatechange` in favor of `script.onload`.

Here is the [compatibility for xhr.onload.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)

[Source of IE11 removing it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, just tested the onload instead of onreadtstatechange with no luck.

Comment: Well I would definitely go with Marco's suggestion above and just use `$.ajax()` instead of wasting time with IE's sillyness.

Comment: I ended up removing the Status==200 check. I get the correct response with just the readystate check in the if. I didn't have time to make the change. Also, I am not sure if the jquery $ajax has .upload progress event.