# async onload not working in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code to asynchronously load an Ad on my site which looks like this:

```
<div id="ad-div"></div>
<script>function onAdReady() {
    debug_log('Method onAdReady called');
    new Ad(document.getElementById("ad-div"))
}
</script>
<script src="http://content.xxxxx.com/ads/ads.min.js" async onload="onAdReady()"></script>
```

The problem is that the `onAdReady` function is never beeing called. The reason for this might be that the html code which contains this snippet is beeing loaded via javascript in the first place like this:

```
// Initiate out_window_view
$.ajax({
    url: loadPagePath("main.html"),
    success: function (result) {
        debug_log("Going in main.html view");
        $("#content").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        debug_log("Error, failed to load out_window_main view");
    }
});
```

This code is beeing executed in the `$(document).ready(function () {]` in case that might matter.
Can anyone expalain to me why this is not working and provide me with a workaround or alternative way for solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to add `async` to an ajax-generated-content. The purpose of `async` script is to allow the browser to keep on parsing the document without waiting for the script to fully load. The onload event is called immediately after the script has finished loading and before DOMReady. In other words, *`async`'s `onload` will **not** fire after DOMReady*.

When you add the snippet to your page, the page has already finished parsing, so the async onload event won't fire.

The solution IMO is to remove the `async` part and just call the function after the `<script>` synchronously.

Comment: Thanks thats a very good explanation. I think I will be able to fix it now

Answer (score 0):

You want to load an ad when the page is loaded?

What do you see in the network tab from the debug tools (firebug or F12 in chrome/Firefox)?

Where do you call $( document ).ready() ?

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Can you tell me when you want to send the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add the script programmatically, it will be `async` by default (reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)), and you can listen to the `onload` or `onreadystatechange` event (as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256620/), IE11 doesn't support `onreadystatechange`). Here is an example:

```
var setup = function(){
  console.log('the script has been parsed');
};

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://content.xxxxx.com/ads/ads.min.js";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

// standard browser
script.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if (this.readyState == 'complete'){
     setup();
  }
}
// IE
script.onload = setup;
```