# XMLHttpRequest.open override not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

So I did an interceptor for XMLHttpRequests by overriding the open. I just want to count the requests and responses.
It works great in all browsers, except IE..

```
export default function interceptXHRRequests(self) {
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.nativeOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    const url = arguments[1];
    if (!url.includes('/kids/_next/')) {
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 1) {
                console.log(self.numberOfRequestsPending)
                self.numberOfRequestsPending++;
            }
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(self.numberOfRequestsPending)
                self.numberOfRequestsPending--;
            }
        };
    }
    this.nativeOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

In chrome for instance it works as it should, goes to a number, let's say 24, and down to 0 after the responses are retrieved, but in Internet Explorer increases more than it decreases.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?
(it is react/js, if it matters for whatever reason)

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256620/onreadystatechange-not-firing-in-ie-for-xhr-request

Comment: If your actual goal is to wait until several ajax requests have completed, I suggest an IE compatible `Promise.all()` approach.